# IBAction causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, exc-bad-access, ibaction

I load a xib and then I need to close that with a button. I am using this:

```
- (IBAction)donePressed:(id)sender {
    printf("Done\n");
    [self check_result];
    printf("Removing View\n");
   [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I load XIB like this :

```
AFUserFeedbackController *moviePlayer_af = [[AFUserFeedbackController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserFeedback" bundle:nil];
UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
moviePlayer_af.view.frame = backgroundWindow.frame;
[backgroundWindow addSubview:moviePlayer_af.view];
```

This is how I mapped it:

[image: http://i.picresize.com/images/2013/02/13/T2AHc.png]

But after pressing the button, all I get is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error and I get this output:

```
(lldb)
```

and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. How can I fix that?

Comment: 1. what does `check_result` do? 2. `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` - ***Oh why?***

Comment: Check the IBAction connected properly? Are you presenting that view controller??

Comment: Does the crash occur on click instantly or after going through the target method?

Comment: The problem is, it does not even reach that point. If it would it would have printed `Done` before anything...

Comment: @AppleDelegate, instantly occur when I click on the button.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this method and see on which line it is crashing?

Comment: @sanjitshaw as i said before it crashes when the button is clicked and it does not run the inside...

Comment: So have you mapped the button action with the proper button in xib? Check once

Comment: @sanjitshaw please look at the picture that I have just put

Comment: Open xib and right click on File Owner, if you see any yellow icon as warning for any of your previous connection, remove that and run the app..

Comment: @iphonic

There is no yellow warning icon there.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)donePressed:(id)sender
{
printf("Done\n");
printf("Removing View\n");
[moviePlayer_af.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```